# Braintree by PayPal

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions

Has anyone tried using PayPal's Braintree and had success in setting it up?

Comment: Had never heard of them until now. If they offered ACH (e-check) processing they'd be worth a try. I currently use Stripe but am looking into other options in order to process e-checks.

Comment: I have found this older extension for Braintree by Paypal. I do not know enough about it to make it work with 4.7.